# Ошибка "The element beneath element is unrecognized".

Tags: delphi, c++

Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2. При компиляции программ (даже пустой формы) выдается всегда одна ошибка

> `Compiling Project1.dproj (Debug, Win32)
> [MSBuild Error] The element beneath element is unrecognized.`

добавил 64 разрядный компилятор - все равно не помогло. ОС Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте с правами Администратора, если получится, то дайте права текущему юзеру на запись в каталоги, необходимые для создания проекта. 
И конечно проверьте правильность установленной DotNet FrameWork 4.0

Comment: тоже самое из правами администратора, что это вообще за ошибка и как ее исправить???

Comment: DotNet FrameWork 4.0 переустановите

Comment: и tNet FrameWork 4.0 уже ставил, и обновлял его, и microsoft c++ visual 2010 x 64 уже ставил, но толку небыло(

Comment: удалите DotNet 4.0 с помощью этой утилиты <br>
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx <br>
Проверьте работу Delphi без установленного DotNet-а <br>
Если потребует DotNet 4.0, установите и проверьте правильность установки с помощью этой утилиты <br>
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx

Comment: Тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630234/teamcity-msbuild-4-0-help вроде тоже боролись похожей ошибкой, решили ручной правкой путей

Comment: [11/04/11,12:53:23] ****ERROR**** Verification failed for product .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 с удалением тоже самое было, назад произвести не удалось

Comment: Обратите внимание, я говорил о DotNet 4.0!!!<br>
.NET Framework 3.5, насколько я знаю, входит в состав Windows 7 - удалять-переустанавливать его не надо - он должен проходить верификацию. Если же с ним возникли проблемы, то скорее всего придется переустанавливать операционную систему.<br><br>
Попробуйте так же спросить помощи здесь <br>http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=33&topic=11977

Comment: я не удалял я воспользовался той программой что вы скинули, вторая не захотела работать вот я только что вручную скачал Microsoft .NET Framework Full 4.0 Final / 4.5 Developer Preview

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/get/yDrg-Zl4/DotNet_Framework_40_Full_Setup.html скачал вот что пишет Сведения

Такая же или более новая версия .NET Framework 4 уже установлена на этом компьютере.

Comment: пробовали удалять с помощью этой утилиты <br>
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx

Comment: удалял, запускал делфи ничего не поменялось, поставил http://www.4shared.com/get/yDrg-Zl4/DotNet_Framework_40_Full_Setup.html и так же ничего не поменялось

Comment: Может скачаете с официального сайта? Мало ли что там на варезных сайтах подсунуть могут <br>
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/ru-ru/details.aspx?familyid=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7&displaylang=ru

Comment: И, конечно, после каждого действия перезагружаться. Если ничего не поможет, похоже придется переустанавливать систему.

Comment: не помогло(((

Comment: Ну тогда, извините, у меня предложения закончились <br>
Попробуйте так же спросить помощи здесь <br>
http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=33&topic=11977 <br>
<br>
ну или переустанавливайте систему - чего уж там